# Running Quadratic Equation solver in C, on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm a little new to programming, I'm trying to write a program to solve quadratic equation, here's my code:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <math.h>
>
> void main (){
>   int a, b, c, delta;
>   float root1, root2;
>   delta = ( b * b ) - ( 4 * a * c );
>   printf("enter a, b, c, in such syntax ax^2 + bx + c:\n");
>   scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
>   printf("You mean %dx^2 + %dx + %d, delta=%f\n\n", a, b, c, delta);
>
>   if ( delta < 0 )
>       printf("The equation has no roots.\n");
>   if ( delta == 0 ){
>       root1 = -b / (2*a);
>       printf("The equaion has one root: %d\n", root1);
>   }
>   if ( delta > 0 ){
>       root1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
>       root2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
>       printf("root 1 = %f\nroot 2 = %f\n", root1, root2);
>   }
> }
> ```

It's compiled without error, the problem is each time I run it, with same input, I get different answers!

> $ ./qe
>   enter a, b, c, in such syntax ax^2 + bx + c:
>   2
>   4
>   2
>   You mean 2x^2 + 4x + 8, delta=0.000000
>
> The equation has no roots.
>   $ ./qe
>   enter a, b, c, in such syntax ax^2 + bx + c:
>   2
>   4
>   2
>   You mean 2x^2 + 4x + 8, delta=0.000000
>
> root 1 = 6543.122070
>   root 2 = -6545.122070
>   $ ./qe
>   enter a, b, c, in such syntax ax^2 + bx + c:
>   2
>   4
>   2
>   You mean 2x^2 + 4x + 8, delta=0.000000
>
> root 1 = 8342.037109
>   root 2 = -8344.037109
>   $ ./qe
>   enter a, b, c, in such syntax ax^2 + bx + c:
>   2
>   4
>   2
>   You mean 2x^2 + 4x + 8, delta=0.000000
>
> The equation has no roots.
>   .
>   .

I'm so confused. Whats the problem? My gcc version: 6.3.1 20170306 (GCC)
how should I fix this?
Thanx.

Comment: Without loops execution in a C program goes from the top to the bottom. Statements aren't executed retroactively. So using `a`, `b` and `c` in a calculation *before* you read into those variables will not work very well.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Your code causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, in the case

```
 delta = ( b * b ) - ( 4 * a * c );
```

`a`, `b`, `c` are used uninitialized. They

- can have trap representation
- do not have their address taken.

So, this invoke UB.

---

You need to

- first check for the success of `scanf()` call
- move the calculation of `delta` after the successful scanning for values for the involved operands.

Also, to add, for a hosted environment, the conforming signature for `main()` would be `int main(void)`, not `void main ()`